# getting <null> when trying to parse JSON response

Tags: web-services, ios, json

i have problem with getting `<null>` when trying to display a `string` on a UILabel or either on the console, here is my code step by step :

```
NSArray *array=[[request responseString]JSONValue];
for (int i=0; i<[array count]; i++) {
NSDictionary *stationEnCours=[array objectAtIndex:i];
NSLog(@"%@",[stationEnCours objectForKey:@"ssiphone_adresse"]);
}
topStation.sstationAdress=[stationEnCours objectForKey:@"ssiphone_adresse"]; //global variable
adresseStation.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",topStation.sstationAdress];//display on label
```

Now for both the console and the label i got `<null>` although i have check it  in my data base it's not null. is that due to JSON parsing rules ? how can i fix it ? thx in advance for help :)
**EDIT :**
here is my response string :

```
    2011-05-12 15:09:38.424 TopStation[1070:207] response string :[
{"ssiphone_idstation":"80","0":"80","ssiphone_etatstation":"true","1":"true","ssiphone_commerce":"true","2":"true","ssiphone_stationdelavage":"false","3":"false","ssiphone_typescarburants":"Sans Plomb 95,SP95-E10,Gazole,GPLc,GNV,","4":"Sans Plomb 95,SP95-E10,Gazole,GPLc,GNV,","ssiphone_joursdelasemaine":"7J\/7","5":"7J\/7","ssiphone_horaires":"24h\/24","6":"24h\/24","ssiphone_telephone":"0400221997","7":"0400221997","ssiphone_sensdecirculation":"(Sens >> Aix-en-Prov.\/Marseille)","8":"(Sens >> Aix-en-Prov.\/Marseille)","ssiphone_adresse":"A 51 - Aire de la Champouse","9":"A 51 - Aire de la Champouse","ssiphone_ville":"BOUC-BEL-AIR","10":"BOUC-BEL-AIR","ssiphone_departement":"13","11":"13","ssiphone_longitude":"5.39532","12":"5.39532","ssiphone_latitude":"43.4416","13":"43.4416","ssiphone_nomstation":"RELAIS TOTAL DE LA CHAMPOUSE","14":"RELAIS TOTAL DE LA CHAMPOUSE","ssiphone_voie":"A 51","15":"A 51","ssiphone_enseigne":"TOTAL","16":"TOTAL","ssiphone_codepostal":"13320","17":"13320","ssiphone_referencegps":"TOTAL DE LA CHAMPOUSE A 51","18":"TOTAL DE LA CHAMPOUSE A 51","distance":17.3},
{"ssiphone_idstation":"86","0":"86","ssiphone_etatstation":"true","1":"true","ssiphone_commerce":"true","2":"true","ssiphone_stationdelavage":"false","3":"false","ssiphone_typescarburants":"SP95-E10,Gazole,Super Gazole,GPLc,GNV,","4":"SP95-E10,Gazole,Super Gazole,GPLc,GNV,","ssiphone_joursdelasemaine":"7J\/7","5":"7J\/7","ssiphone_horaires":"24h\/24","6":"24h\/24","ssiphone_telephone":"0442591667","7":"0442591667","ssiphone_sensdecirculation":"","8":"","ssiphone_adresse":null,"9":null,"ssiphone_ville":"AIX-EN-PROVENCE","10":"AIX-EN-PROVENCE","ssiphone_departement":"13","11":"13","ssiphone_longitude":"5.43361","12":"5.43361","ssiphone_latitude":"43.5194","13":"43.5194","ssiphone_nomstation":"STATION BP","14":"STATION BP","ssiphone_voie":"","15":"","ssiphone_enseigne":"BP","16":"BP","ssiphone_codepostal":"13100","17":"13100","ssiphone_referencegps":"BP AIX EN PROVENCE","18":"BP AIX EN PROVENCE","distance":25.3},{"ssiphone_idstation":"89","0":"89","ssiphone_etatstation":"true","1":"true","ssiphone_commerce":"true","2":"true","ssiphone_stationdelavage":"false","3":"false","ssiphone_typescarburants":"SP95-E10,E85,Gazole,Super Gazole,GPLc,","4":"SP95-E10,E85,Gazole,Super Gazole,GPLc,","ssiphone_joursdelasemaine":"7J\/7","5":"7J\/7","ssiphone_horaires":null,"6":null,"ssiphone_telephone":"0442264052","7":"0442264052","ssiphone_sensdecirculation":"(Centre ville) (A8 sortie 31)","8":"(Centre ville) (A8 sortie 31)","ssiphone_adresse":"467 Avenue Henri Mauriat","9":"467 Avenue Henri Mauriat","ssiphone_ville":"AIX-EN-PROVENCE","10":"AIX-EN-PROVENCE","ssiphone_departement":"13","11":"13","ssiphone_longitude":"5.4661","12":"5.4661","ssiphone_latitude":"43.5157","13":"43.5157","ssiphone_nomstation":null,"14":null,"ssiphone_voie":"","15":"","ssiphone_enseigne":"TOTAL","16":"TOTAL","ssiphone_codepostal":"13090","17":"13090","ssiphone_referencegps":"TOTAL DE L'ARC","18":"TOTAL DE L'ARC","distance":24.9},{"ssiphone_idstation":"91","0":"91","ssiphone_etatstation":"true","1":"true","ssiphone_commerce":"true","2":"true","ssiphone_stationdelavage":"false","3":"false","ssiphone_typescarburants":"Sans Plomb 95,Sans Plomb 98,Gazole,Super Gazole,GPLc,GNV,","4":"Sans Plomb 95,Sans Plomb 98,Gazole,Super Gazole,GPLc,GNV,","ssiphone_joursdelasemaine":"7J\/7","5":"7J\/7","ssiphone_horaires":"L-S: 7h30-20h","6":"L-S: 7h30-20h","ssiphone_telephone":"0442958459","7":"0442958459","ssiphone_sensdecirculation":"(Dir.>> Aix Ouest) ","8":"(Dir.>> Aix Ouest) ","ssiphone_adresse":"Route de Berre - Jas de Bouffan","9":"Route de Berre - Jas de Bouffan","ssiphone_ville":"AIX-EN-PROVENCE","10":"AIX-EN-PROVENCE","ssiphone_departement":"13","11":"13","ssiphone_longitude":"5.41778","12":"5.41778","ssiphone_latitude":"43.5342","13":"43.5342","ssiphone_nomstation":null,"14":null,"ssiphone_voie":"","15":"","ssiphone_enseigne":"CASINO","16":"CASINO","ssiphone_codepostal":"13090","17":"13090","ssiphone_referencegps":"CASINO AIX EN PROVENCE","18":"CASINO AIX EN PROVENCE","distance":27.1}]
```

**EDIT:**

the response is coded like this in the server side :

```
 $stationsFinales=array();
           $stationsFinales=$this->EpurationStations($stationsIdeales);

           sendResponse(200,json_encode($stationsFinales));
           return true;
```

Comment: How is the json string generated in the web service?  Is that code under your control?

Comment: it's generated pretty well, there is no `<null>`
 when i try to display the response on server side, the string is string, the numeric is numeric, as i expect, the problem is only on iPhone side when parsing :(

Comment: The responseString contains `null`.  This is _before_ the JSON parser (on the iOS device) parses the string into objects.

Comment: ok, i do agree with that, but first, why on server side  it's not `null` ? second how can i do to prevent this, i have checked the real String which is parsed as `<null>`, it's : `Boulevard - 6th road`, there is no special character which may prevent parsing

Comment: Checked in the db or in the server code which generates the json response?

Comment: Hi, i have edited my post, also i want to mention that the `<null>` value is not for all values, for exemple, i have returned two stations from web-service, the first is ok and the second is `<null>`, that's which make me confused

Comment: Is that PHP?  I don't know how in PHP you can check the response before sending but you should verify there first and if that is ok then the problem might be in how requestString is being set.

Comment: Hi Anna, i have checked with displaying the response before sending it and i have found that the value `<null>` displayed in iPhone side is also `<null>` in server side before being encoded by JSON, so the problem may become from the DataBase encodage ?? please correct me if i am wrong, by the way, the encodage of that field is `utf8_unicode_ci`

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not familiar with PHP and I don't know what kind of db you are using but most dbs allow "nullable" fields so even if type is "string" it can be "null" (meaning no value provided).  You might want to ask a new question with PHP and MySQL (?) tags to get a better answer.  But I thought you saw a value in the db for those fields?

Comment: well, first i would like to thank you for your help Anna, that's it, there is no problem with JSON, it's all about MySql encodage i guess, because i have noticed that all null values are frensh words like 'Maréchal', so all words with accent will be transformed into `<null>` when parsing :)

Comment: You're welcome and I'm sure there's a solution for the accent problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know JSON very well but when I used it in my application, I solved a problem like this by using `valueForKey:` instead of `objectForKey:` and try to use this code:

```
NSArray *array = [[request responseString] JSONValue];

for (int i = 0; i < [array count]; i++) {
    NSDictionary *stationEnCours = [array objectAtIndex:i];
    NSLog(@"%@", [stationEnCours valueForKey:@"ssiphone_adresse"]);
    topStation.sstationAdress = [stationEnCours valueForKey:@"ssiphone_adresse"];
}

adresseStation.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", topStation.sstationAdress];
```

Consider this answer only as a test because, as I've said before, I don't know JSON very well.
However, I hope this can help you like me!

Comment: Hi, thx for your answer, however nothing have been changed, the `<null>` is always generated when parsing :)

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry... But instead of using an array and then JSONValue, why don't you use a framework? Maybe I solved with valueForKey: because I'm using JSON Framework by Stig Brautaset... (http://stig.github.com/json-framework/) ;)